# Нужно ли выделять запятыми «дорогой мне»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

Нужно ли отделять запятыми «дорогой мне»? Или это не уточнение?

*Однако в силу того, что вы тот самый(,) дорогой мне(,) человек...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Однако из-за того, что вы тот самый, **дорогой мне,** человек..*

Вариант без обособления **некорректен**: определительный **оборот** "дорогой мне" **уточняет** содержание указательного местоимения "тот самый", **неоднородных** отношений там не может быть.

Лучше убрать союз **"в силу того"** – он не подходит сюда по стилю.

Вариант с одной запятой (однородные отношения) возможен, но он менее выразителен:  *Однако из-за того, что вы тот самый, **дорогой мне** человек..*

Comment: *Вариант с одной запятой (однородные отношения) возможен* — теоретически да, но не на практике. Попробуйте вставить союз И. Как звучит?

Comment: Я не люблю подстановки, так как они иногда напоминают мне логические  «подставки», которыми любили пользоваться софисты (намеренное ведение в заблуждение всякими логическими уловками). Могу я сказать так: Стояла темная и белунная ночь. Была жестокая и холодная зима. Вроде бы нет. Значит, это неоднородные определения, да? А они однородные, потому что  здесь важен смысл, а не союз И. Раскрывается одна тема, каждое определение относится к существительному независимо: тот самый человек, дорогой мне человек.

Comment: Впрочем, зачем я вам всё это рассказываю? Здесь  же все молодцы, кроме меня, вот в чем загадка. Потому что они все  думают правильно, В ОДНОм ПРАВИЛЬНОМ  направлении, как их научили думать.  Вы, например,  векторную алгебру изучали в школе (коллинеарные однонаправленные векторы)? Мне приходилось... Даже сказку написала на эту тему, учителя хвалили.

Comment: Векторы — это из геометрии, их все проходят. Есть ещё один способ проверки целесообразности однородности — поменять местами: вы дорогой мне, тот самый человек. Даже если "то самый" подразумевает что-то похожее (однородное) — даже и не представляю, что это могло бы быть, — то необходимо переформулировать предложение (чтобы оно нормально звучало), как и в вашем случае. В ваших примерах больше подходит пояснительная запятая (например, тёмная, потому что безлунная). Кстати, вставлять сочинительный союз даже Розенталь предлагает, так что авторитетный метод, но перестановка местами лучше.

Comment: Ах, oleedd , чтобы понять эту тему, надо перейти в другое пространство мышления, а здесь всё грубо, дискретно, условно  и очень далеко от истины. Мне бы и хотелось вам рассказать, но вы меня не услышите,  перебьёте на первом же слове.  Поэтому пусть всё остается так, как хотите вы  и как хотят все остальные. « Это предложение пунктуационно можно оформить по-разному»  – лучше и не скажешь.  А если появится желание знать, чувствовать и понимать больше, то придут и сами спросят.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае ***дорогой мне*** является уточнением. Запятые нужны.

[**Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4) (справочник Розенталя)

> Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений ***этот, тот, такой, каждый, один*** (в значении местоимения) и т. п.: *Хотелось отличиться перед этим, **дорогим для меня,** человеком* (М. Г.)...

Comment: Александр, а что вы скажете о так называемых пояснительных определениях у Розенталя: Так называемые пояснительные определения однородными не являются; запятая между ними ставится, если второе определение поясняет первое (между ними можно вставить слова то есть или а именно): Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и… увидел совершенно другие, мне незнакомые места (Т.); http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Comment: А что о них можно сказать? Здесь пояснительные, там уточнительные. Иногда разница неочевидна. Часто и там и там подставляются "то есть" или "а именно" (кстати, в предложении из вопроса они бы не очень красиво звучали). А метод подстановки, насколько я знаю, вы не приветствуете.

Comment: Интересно узнать, почему вы против варианта без обособления? Это же тот самый, интонационный, принцип.  :)  В нацкорпусе есть несколько примеров без запятых (правда, мне попались совсем старые, конец 19 века и до реформы 1956 года).

Comment: Александр, я же задала вам вполне конкретный вопрос. Здесь возможны два вида отношений: уточнение (с обособлением) и однородные отношения (одна запятая). Второй вариант есть у Розенталя, но вы не допускаете его?  Или допускаете? Интонационно они оба возможны. Помните: Еще одно, последнее сказанье — И летопись окончена моя.  Также: Эти были СВОИ, слободские люди.

Comment: Не ставить запятые вообще? Тогда контекст нужен особый, точно подходящий под ситуацию. Как раз мне хотелось попросить автора добавить его.  Такие нюансы надо оговаривать, а не отвечать, что все подойдет. Так можно считать, что все три варианта возможны, но вот вы выбираете один.

Comment: Извините, "не прочел" конкретный вопрос. Мое мнение такое: эта тема запутанная, многогранная, Розенталь собирал, анализировал примеры и как-то их классифицировал. Видимо, на данном этапе возможен выбор – как сам автор хочет преподнести определения. В своем же ответе я хотел дать ссылку на конкретное правило (чтобы можно было ткнуть пальцем и не сомневаться).

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за ваше мнение.  Тут дело не в классификации., а в смысловых и грамматических нюансах, заложенных в каждом варианте. Как у нас любят здесь говорить: написать можно по-разному, ошибки не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Это предложение пунктуационно можно оформить по-разному.

1. Вариант с обособленным (уточняющим) определением "дорогой мне" вполне корректен.

...***вы тот самый, дорогой мне, человек...*** Вопрос к уточнению: *а именно какой?*

Ср.: *Кой-где выглянули женские, /большей частью старушечьи/, головы* (И. Тургенев).

Уточняющими называются члены предложения, которые уточняют, конкретизируют предшествующий член предложения и выполняют одинаковую с ним синтаксическую функцию.

2. Вариант без обособления тоже возможен. При этом меняется интонация при чтении, она становится ровной, без акцента на слове "дорогой":

..***.вы тот самый дорогой мне человек...***

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от интонации и вкладываемого смысла здесь могут быть различные варианты пунктуационного оформления, в т. ч. и с запятой после ***тот***:

*Однако в силу того, что вы тот, **самый дорогой** мне человек...*

При отсутствии запятой после ***тот*** или ***самый*** предложение может быть прочитано двояко:

*Однако в силу того, что вы **тот самый** дорогой мне человек...*

*Однако в силу того, что вы тот **самый дорогой** мне человек...*